# ExceptionConverter com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils$InlineImageParseException: Could not find image data or EI 420

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText to extract Text from PDF, however, I had the following exception, and it cannot be caught by try/catch(Exception e), I have attached the file here, actually I don't care very much whether I can extract text from it, I just want to know how to catch the exception.

Exception:

```
ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils$InlineImageParseException: Could not find image data or EI
420
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.parseInlineImageSamples(InlineImageUtils.java:386)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.parseInlineImage(InlineImageUtils.java:156)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:427)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:80)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(PdfTextExtractor.java:74)
```

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4l4ioqzpcca05vc/Understanding%20the%20High%20Photocatalytic%20Activity%20of%20%28B%2C%20Ag%29-Codopeda312205c_si_001.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Which version of iText are you using. We've fixed this problem abour a year ago.

Comment: Hmm, that's the most recent version. Inline images are a pain. I'm answering from my phone, so I can't check what's going on with the file.

Comment: WoW, you are so devoted! Help me please when you are available, thank you a lot! By the way, one thing I cannot figure out is why the exception cannot be caught, which makes my program stop every time it meets such file... @BrunoLowagie

Answer (score 1):

The problematic inline Image is

```
q 12 0 0 1.5 598.5 2905.5 cm
BI
/CS/RGB
/W 8
/H 1
/BPC 8
/F[/A85
/Fl]
/DP[null
<</Predictor 15
/Columns 8
/Colors 3>>]
ID
Gar9F/1Xl3A2+09nF?)T!(_,53r~>
EI Q
```

on page 5. The `null` unfortunately is parsed as `PdfLiteral` with value "null", not as `PdfNull` instance. Thus, `PdfReader.decodeBytes()` throws an exception in

```
PdfObject dpEntry = getPdfObject(dp.get(j));
if (dpEntry instanceof PdfDictionary){
    decodeParams = (PdfDictionary)dpEntry;
} else if (dpEntry == null || dpEntry instanceof PdfNull) {
    decodeParams = null;
} else {
    throw new UnsupportedPdfException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("the.decode.parameter.type.1.is.not.supported", dpEntry.getClass().toString()));
}
```

Replacing

```
} else if (dpEntry == null || dpEntry instanceof PdfNull) {
```

by

```
} else if (dpEntry == null || dpEntry instanceof PdfNull || (dpEntry instanceof PdfLiteral && Arrays.equals("null".getBytes(), ((PdfLiteral)dpEntry).getBytes()))) {
```

makes the code work for the OP's PDF.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis, I really appreciate it. However, if I don't override the class, how can I catch the exception?

Comment: `try-catch(Exception)` or `try-catch(ExceptionConverter)` around your `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` call.

Comment: Let me try ExceptionConverter, Exception does not work as I have already tested that. Thanks!

Comment: Hhmmm, that sounds implausible, `ExceptionConverter` is a `RuntimeException` which in turn is an `Exception`. You might want to add the code around your `PdfTextExtractor` call to allow reproducing the catching issues. That been said, try to catch `Throwable`,.if you cannot catch like that, you actually have another exception elsewhere.

Comment: The fix provided by @mkl has been applied to `PdfReader`: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/02e970e28c491ebbeccd58b19df612b11a601087